# 4 different orders need to be assigned to one customer

Tags: magento-1.9

So this is frustrating me a little, I joined the company 8 months ago, Magento is used and I have been learning how to use it and make it better for the company. This has been successful, however upon updating the database and training staff to input correctly, some orders are created as new with details missing etc, I need to combine these processed orders with the original account. Is this possible? Highly frustrating. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
   <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
umask(0);
Mage::app('admin'); 
        $oder_id = 1298;
        $CustomerId = 1951;
        $CustomerEmail = 'sprts12000@yahoo.com';
        $CustomerFirstname = 'Edward';
        $CustomerLastname = 'McCool';
        $order     = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($oder_id); 
         if($order){
                $order->setCustomerId($CustomerId);
                $order->setCustomerEmail($CustomerEmail);
                $order->setCustomerFirstname($CustomerFirstname);
                $order->setCustomerLastname($CustomerLastname);     

                $order->save();

        }
        ?>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for this, why edward etc? where will i place this code?

Comment: Or do i have to change the name for each duplicate we have on the system?

Comment: Do you know coding in magento ?? create a new file and place it on root folder

Comment: 'edward' is refer to an existing customer.It just a example to show you.

Comment: s there an available plug-in which will give the option within Magento itself rather than running into the world of code?